# How to plot filtered values from datagrid?

Tags: c#, sql, charts, windows-forms-designer

It is clear how to plot values we have in original table, but how to plot values when they were filtered, that is the question

These lines of code help us to show our sql table in datagrid and plot values without being filtered

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace graphic
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            this.values1TableAdapter.Fill(this.dataGraphicDataSet.values1);

        }

        private void TextBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            BindingSource bs = new BindingSource();
            bs.DataSource = dataGridView1.DataSource;
            bs.Filter = "Convert(ederpou , 'System.String') LIKE '" + textBox1.Text + "%'";
            dataGridView1.DataSource = bs;
        }

        private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            chart1.Series["Series1"].XValueMember = "date";
            chart1.Series["Series1"].YValueMembers = "money";

            chart1.DataSource = dataGraphicDataSet.values1;
            chart1.DataBind();
        }
    }
}
```

After clicking Load buttom we get this

[image]

but how to get for example plot of those values where there is filter on "ederpou" = 323232?

[image]

Comment: You simply bind to the fltered source. I would also recommend never to bind to the whole chart but to a `series.Points`.

Comment: DataTable filteredTable = this.dataGraphicDataSet.values1.Where(x => x.Field<int>("ederpou")).CopyToDataTable();  Then bind to new table.

Comment: @TaW what exactly do you mean, because i am total newbie in c#. I see there is `chart1.DataBind();` function, but how to bind to the filtered data idk

Comment: `chart1.Series["Series1"].Points.DataBind..` There are a few overloads but they should all work for you. You should be able to bind to the same Bindingsource

Comment: @TaW nah.. need certain lines of code to delete and particular new to write

Comment: I don't understand. Here is an example: `void loadChart()
{
    chart1.Series["Series1"].Points.DataBind(bs, "ID", "val", "");
    chart1.DataBind();
}` - Do move the declaration of the bs out of the code: `BindingSource bs = new BindingSource();

        private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            bs = new BindingSource();...` - Do use your own mebernames!

Comment: @TaW appreciate your help, but still do not understand what to delete and what to write